# Using colorbox in a Listing/minipage with underscore "_"

Tags: listings, color, minipage

I am having some issues with using `\colorbox{}{}` in combination with an underscore.

The Listing will compile without issues and highlighting the text properly, but as soon as I have an underscore in the text to be highlighted, I get the same error like 100 times.

```
pdflatex> l.215 ...red_3      \!\colorbox{lightred}{Man_3}!
pdflatex>                                                    . )
pdflatex> ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
pdflatex> <recently read> \egroup
```

I've tried escaping that "_" with slash, but that does not help.

```
        \documentclass[ a4paper,                        % DinA4 Paper
            % abstract      = on,           % enable abstract (not in scrbook})
            draft           = false,        % status: draft, final
            twoside         = false,        % set true for 2-sided
            pdftex,                         % PDF
            pagesize,
            BCOR            = 10mm,
            open            = any,          % right, left   
            headings        = normal,       % alt: big, normal
            fontsize        = 12pt,         % font size
            parskip         = full+,        % alt: half+-*
            1.1headlines,   
            appendixprefix  = false,
            chapterprefix   = false,    
            %titlepage,
            notitlepage,                    % no cleardoublepage 
            headinclude,
            numbers         = noenddot,     % no end dot in headings
            % listof        = totoc,        % add LoF to ToC
            % index         = totoc,        % Index
            bibliography    = totoc         % Bib to ToC
            ]{scrbook}  % scrbook,scrreprt
         \usepackage[english]{babel} % hyphenation etc.
         \usepackage{color} 
         \definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0.4}   % Light Redish Color
         \usepackage{listings}      % llistings         
         \lstset{ 
          float             = htpb,     % listings are floats, no page breaks
           language         = C,                    
           basicstyle       = \ttfamily\scriptsize,         
           backgroundcolor  = \color{white},    
           numbers          = none,                     
           numberstyle      = \tiny\color{gray},    
           stepnumber       = 2,                 
           numbersep            = 5pt,      
           showspaces       = false,                
           showstringspaces = false,         
           showtabs         = false,                 
           frame                = single,                       
           rulecolor            = \color{black},        
           tabsize          = 2,                        
           captionpos       = b,                    
           breaklines       = true,                
           breakatwhitespace    = false,            
           title                = \lstname,                     
           keywordstyle     = \bfseries\color{black},     
           commentstyle     = \color{black},   
           stringstyle      = \color{black}, 
           escapechar       = \! ,    
           %escapeinside        = {\%*}{*)},       
           morekeywords     = {*,SEQ,...}          
         }

         \begin{document}
         \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
         \lstset{caption = {Caption},label = {label}}
         \begin{lstlisting}
         Hello
         \!\colorbox{lightred}{Highlighted}!
         \end{lstlisting}
         \end{minipage}
         \end{document}
```

The code above gets rendered as it should, but as soon as I add an "_" it does not work.

Does anybody have a clue, how I can use the colorbox on a underscored word in the example?

Comment: `\usepackage{underscore}` or `\string_`. Also you should better make complete example instead of letting us assemble your snippets.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look to the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The <code>\usepackage{underscore}</code> works in my small example, but as I have escaped all underscores in my 100+ pages, this breaks my document... Or is there some easy way to "migrate" my document to use the underscore package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping the underscore works just fine:

[image]

### Notes:

- You have `escapechar = \!` which defines that you are escaping to LaTeX, hence the underscore is one of those special characters that need to be escaped. Otherwise it is interpreted as a subscript.
- Also, when composing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), you should try to eliminate an unnecessary options and packages that are not required to reproduce the problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper,                        % DinA4 Paper
            % abstract      = on,           % enable abstract (not in scrbook})
            draft           = false,        % status: draft, final
            twoside         = false,        % set true for 2-sided
            pdftex,                         % PDF
            pagesize,
            BCOR            = 10mm,
            open            = any,          % right, left   
            headings        = normal,       % alt: big, normal
            fontsize        = 12pt,         % font size
            parskip         = full+,        % alt: half+-*
            1.1headlines,   
            appendixprefix  = false,
            chapterprefix   = false,    
            %titlepage,
            notitlepage,                    % no cleardoublepage 
            headinclude,
            numbers         = noenddot,     % no end dot in headings
            % listof        = totoc,        % add LoF to ToC
            % index         = totoc,        % Index
            bibliography    = totoc         % Bib to ToC
            ]{scrbook}  % scrbook,scrreprt
         \usepackage[english]{babel} % hyphenation etc.
         \usepackage{color} 
         \definecolor{lightred}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0.4}   % Light Redish Color
         \usepackage{listings}      % llistings         
         \lstset{ 
          float             = htpb,     % listings are floats, no page breaks
           language         = C,                    
           basicstyle       = \ttfamily\scriptsize,         
           backgroundcolor  = \color{white},    
           numbers          = none,                     
           numberstyle      = \tiny\color{gray},    
           stepnumber       = 2,                 
           numbersep            = 5pt,      
           showspaces       = false,                
           showstringspaces = false,         
           showtabs         = false,                 
           frame                = single,                       
           rulecolor            = \color{black},        
           tabsize          = 2,                        
           captionpos       = b,                    
           breaklines       = true,                
           breakatwhitespace    = false,            
           title                = \lstname,                     
           keywordstyle     = \bfseries\color{black},     
           commentstyle     = \color{black},   
           stringstyle      = \color{black}, 
           escapechar       = \! ,    
           %escapeinside        = {\%*}{*)},       
           morekeywords     = {*,SEQ,...}          
         }

         \begin{document}
         \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
         \lstset{caption = {Caption},label = {label}}
         \begin{lstlisting}
             Hello
             High_lighted
             \!\colorbox{lightred}{Highlighted}!
             \!\colorbox{lightred}{High\_lighted}!
         \end{lstlisting}
         \end{minipage}
         \end{document}
```